# Regular Expression Challenge: For every consecutive 6 characters, there must be two 1s (alphabet {"0", "1"})

Tags: regex

So, I want to built a regular expression that I can pass in a string of 0s and 1s (e.g. "0010101000111100100011110001101100011") and then make sure that for every 6 consecutive characters, there needs to be at least two 1s in that block.

Also, strings less than length 6 should pass.

Examples of passing strings:

- ""
- "00"
- "11000011"
- "01010100"

Examples of failing strings:

- "110000000011"
- "000001"

These examples are of very small strings, but I want to build one to take any length string.

Now, I'm looking for a nice way to express this in a regular expression, rather than having solution with a loop and such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use this regex and check that it *doesn't* match:

```
/000000|000001|000010|000100|001000|010000|100000/
```

Comment: What about `001001`?  or `010010`? or `010101`?

Comment: @Chris, there are 2 1's in these examples, so they should be fine.

Comment: but not two consecutive 1s, which is the stated requirement

Comment: I didn't find this in the requirement: 'for every 6 consecutive characters, there needs to be at least two 1s in that block'

Answer (score 2):

Here is a regex that should do the trick (matches valid strings):

```
^((?!0{6}|10{5}|010{4}|001000|000100|0{4}10|0{5}1)[01])+$
```

Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/VelZ1Iqml6

This uses a negative lookahead inside of a repetition so that the condition is checked at every location in the string.

If you are able to just check for strings that don't match, that is more straightforward, and you can use davidrac's solution or this slightly shortened version (which I use in the lookahead of my regex):

```
0{6}|10{5}|010{4}|001000|000100|0{4}10|0{5}1
```

Comment: your regex accepts 10001000 which doesn't meet the requirements

Comment: @MichalKlouda - I edited my original answer, it no longer accepts that.

Comment: nice idea, but still.. the updated one doesn't accept 1000010 which is valid

Comment: @MichalKlouda - No it isn't, the tail end of that string is "000010".

Comment: yep, sorrry... my eyes are tired ;) +1 for that